# Generalized Extreme Value Distribution in C++ (GEV)

Tags: c++, c++11, random, distribution

the GEV Distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution) has 3 parameters:

μ ∈ R — location,

σ > 0 — scale

ξ ∈ R — shape

However, the C++ 11 library only supports a extreme_value_distribution that only supports 2 parameters:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/extreme_value_distribution/

So this implementation lacks the shape parameter (ξ). Is there a way to generate random numbers in C++ with a GEV distribution?

Edit: Wikipedia suggest that the GEV can be constructed from EV, Weibull, and Frechet. So it seems that it can be constructed by using the EV and the Weibull implementation in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used wolfram alpha to find the IDCF of the GEV for ξ!=0: [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e16mat77hum) and 
ξ==0: [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427esddm835st9)

Here is an implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <cmath> 

double icdf(double x, double mu, double sigma, double xi)
{
    if(xi == 0)
    {
        return (mu - sigma * log(-log(x))); 
    }
    else
    {
        double a = pow(-1*log(x),-1*xi);
        double b = -1*xi*mu*pow(-log(x),xi);
        double c = sigma * pow(-log(x),xi) - sigma;
        return (-1)*(a*(b+c) )/xi;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0,1);

    for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i)
    {
        double number = distribution(generator);
        std::cout << icdf(number, 11.328, 2.909, -0.177) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I analyzed the data in Matlab and it looks great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a probabilist, but I'm reasonably sure you can find the cumulative distribution function's inverse and apply that to values taken from a uniform distribution on (0,1]. From the provided Wikipedia link, the inverse for the general case would be

F^-1(x; mu, sigma, xi) = mu + ((-ln x)^(-xi) - 1)*sigma/xi

(assuming I've not slipped up, but it's easy to check yourself). All you'd have to do is apply this function to values pulled from a uniform (0,1], and the resulting values should be distributed as you require. Of course, the xi = 0 case will fail if you attempt to compute values this way, but that case is implemented by the extreme_value_distribution anyway.

Apologies for the formatting, I'm familiar with LaTeX but completely unfamiliar with how to use it when commenting here.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is a good idea, I will post my implementation

Comment: Looks like you've implemented it correctly, I'm glad it worked out! Could you possibly upvote/choose my answer please? As a very new user here I can't even comment on others' answers yet!